# How to make Laravel return a View's "Content-Type" header as "application/javascript"?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to output a dynamic javascript file for inclusion from external websites with the `[script src=""]` tag. As the view is using the Blade engine, it's rendered as `text/html`.

I'd like the `Content-Type` header to be set to `application/javascript` for this view only to avoid Chrome bugging me with messages like "`Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html:`"

My controller:

```
{
    // ...
    return View::make('embedded')->with('foo', $foo);
}
```

The view itself:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/javascript; charset=UTF-8', true);
?>(function(jQuery) {
    // append stylesheets to <head>
    var file;
    // ...
})(jQuery);
```

I've found that I can use `header()` in my view to add custom headers like `X-Content-Type` as expected, however when I try to redefine the `Content-Type` header it doesn't seem to do anything even with the `replace` parameter set as `true`.

I'm surely missing something obvious here, would appreciate your pointing it out to me :)

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Laravel lets you modify header information via the Response class, so you have to make use of it. Remove the `header` line from your view and try it like this in your controller:

```
$contents = View::make('embedded')->with('foo', $foo);
$response = Response::make($contents, $statusCode);
$response->header('Content-Type', 'application/javascript');
return $response;
```

Comment: And realistically the controller is the ideal place to be messing with headers not the view anyway ;)

Comment: This isn't working .!!! I am getting make () not defined i have inherited the response already.

Comment: @sam: It should work with Laravel 4, but won't with Laravel 5.

Answer (score 14):

In Laravel 5.4 you can do this:

```
$contents = view('embedded')->with('foo', $foo);
return response($contents)->header('Content-Type', 'application/javascript');
```

BTW, there is no need to set the header in the view.

Comment: when I tried this one I got "Undefined method 'header'.intelephense(1013) "

Answer (score 12):

In Laravel 5.6:

```
return response()
    ->view('embedded', ['foo' => $foo])
    ->header('Content-Type', 'application/javascript');
```

Answer (score 3):

If you just have JSON in a variable and you want to send it to the browser with the proper content-type set in the header, all you need to do is this:

```
return Response::json($json);
```

assuming, obviously, that `$json` contains your JSON.

Depending on the details of your situation it might make more sense to use views (rather than building your JSON by concatenating strings) but this is still an option if you use a view to build the string.  Something approximately along these lines should work:

```
$json = View::make('some_view_template_that_makes_json') -> with ('some_variable', $some_variable)
return Response::json($json);
```

(Apologies if I missed some part of the question that requires a more manual approach!  At least this should be useful to someone else coming here and wondering how to send JSON from Laravel with the right content-type set.)

Answer (score 3):

Response::json() is not available anymore.

You can use response->json() instead.

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\ResponseFactory;
$foobar = ['foo' => 0, 'bar' => 'baz'];
return response()->json($foobar);
```

Gives:

```
{"foo":0,"bar":"baz"}
```

With the corresponding headers.

Comment: Worked for me Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me
`return Response::view($landing)->header('X-Frame-Options', 'DENY');`