# Laravel 5 XML Parsing

Tags: google-maps, laravel

I have created a storelocator.php in my view with the following code :

```
<?php

$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0"); 
$node = $dom->createElement("markers");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);

header("Content-type: text/xml");

foreach ($results as $value) {   // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE   
    $node = $dom->createElement("marker");   
    $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);  
    $newnode->setAttribute("name",$value->dealer_name);  
    $newnode->setAttribute("address", $value->address);  
    $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $value->lat);  
    $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $value->lng);  
    $newnode->setAttribute("type", $value->outlet_type); 
}

echo $dom->saveXML();

?>
```

My Route is:

```
Route::get('/storelocator','SearchController@showReviews');
```

my ShowReviews Function

```
public function showReviews() {

    //$dealer_address = dealer_addresss::lists('dealer_name','address','lat','lng','outlet_type');
    //return view('/reviews',compact('dealer_address')); 
    $results = DB::table('dealer_address')->get();

    //return view('/reviewresults',compact('results'));

    return view('/storelocator',compact('results')); 
}
```

All I get is a blank page:
When I click on source I am able to the xml content with the data but on hover it says
Attempt to use an XML processing instruction in HTML.

What am I doing wrong here ? Any guide would be immensely appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used this:

https://github.com/SoapBox/laravel-formatter

to make proper XML.

You probably have an error in your xml file.

Also, sending header in view is already too late.

Send it in your controller.

Related: [How to make Laravel return a View's "Content-Type" header as "application/javascript"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18685321/how-to-make-laravel-return-a-views-content-type-header-as-application-javasc)